# Importing modules and accessing files from other packages

Tags: python

I've got the following project structure [image]

The speech_recognition.py (which is my main module atm) runs through my IDE (pyCharm) but when I try to run it through the terminal using `python speech_recognition.py` I get [image]

Another thing is that I try to access the `system_config` file in the `Configurations` folder in the mic_config file this way:

```
def __init__(self, path = "../Configurations/system_config"):
    with open(path) as json_data:
        self.mic_config = json.load(json_data)
        json_data.close()
```

And I get the following exception:[image]

So how do I fix these problems:
1. Importing modules from other packages
2. Accessing files using a relative path

Thanks!

Comment: From which directory are you running it in the command line?

Comment: The `Smart Home` directory although I've also tried from the `Speech Recognition` one to get the import to work

Comment: @Shookie Avoid package directories with spaces. Access files from other packages via `pkg_resources`, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711085/introduction-tutorial-to-pkg-resources. Avoid having changing data files placed within your python code, separate it.

Comment: Avoid spaces in dir names, and place the dirs on your pythonpath

Comment: @JanVlcinsky - Will do. However I did place the changing data files (config files) in their own Configuration folder. Is that not okay?

Comment: @Shookie Yes, it is fine. I meant more the *.wav file inside `Speech Recognition`

Comment: This project looks like fun :D

Comment: @JoelCornett - Hopefully it will be when I finish it! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Re: non existing file:

```
def __init__(self, path = "../Configurations/system_config"):
    with open(path) as json_data:
        self.mic_config = json.load(json_data)
        json_data.close()
```

When Python opens the file, it searches the path from current directory. It seems like you are expecting that Python searches from the directory, the module is located at.

Typical solution is:

- decide to run your script from your project root
- assume existence of subdirectory `Configurations/system_config`
- let your code open from here

Then your code could look like:

```
def __init__(self, path = "Configurations/system_config"):
    with open(path) as json_data:
        self.mic_config = json.load(json_data)
        json_data.close()
```

## Where is root of your project

It is not clear, where is your project having root. If it is `Smart Home`, then it is not clear, why you have in this folder `__init__.py` file, it shall not be there.

In case your project home is at `Workspace`, then you run into problems with a space in submodule `Smart Home`.

### Where is your `setup.py`

`setup.py` is typical part of Python projects, containing modules and packages to use. When one starts programming in Python, it often seems to be something unimportant, too complex, and is first candidate to skip.

In fact, `setup.py` is sort of project meta information and is entry point for many tools (installers, IDE, ...). It allows defining other packages which shall be installed, where are your packages and modules located, provide short and long description.

Take care of it and it may become anchor of your project.

## Problems with importing your packages

This is related to two things

- where you start your program from
- use of `setup.py`

Both was discussed above.

Typical scenario is:

- root of your project is at `Smart Home`
- no `__init__.py` in project directory
- add `setup.py` to project root
- let your IDE know, where the root of your project is

If you `cd` to your project root, you shall be able (even without `setup.py`) to:

1. open `python` (or better `iPython`) console
2. succeed with `import Parsers`
3. succeed with `import Parsers.listener_config`
4. succeed with `import SpeechRecognition` # mind, that there is no space, rename your dir
5. succeed with `import SpeechRecognition.speech_recongintion`

If you fail with this, you have either misspelled names, or space in names, or broken code, which cannot be loaded.

## Where to learn more about `setup.py`

There is large progress in this area within last 2 years, so you can easily get confused by contradicting obsolete information.

Simple rule: prefer using `pip` as a command line tools and `setuptools` as a library to build your packages.

Both are installed with another great tool `virtualenv`.

[`setuptools` and `distribute` got merged](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/merge-faq.html) about a year ago - this was very important step simplifying the mess. So best place to start is probably [`setuptools` doc](http://pythonhosted.org//setuptools/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've done what you said and it works! 
Just one question though - I'd like to learn a bit more about the `setup.py` like you said. Do you know a good resource perhaps?

Comment: @Shookie There is large progress in this area within last 2 years, so you can easily get confused by contradicting obsolete information.
Simple rule: prefer using `pip` as a command line tools and `setuptools` as a library to build your packages. [`setuptools` and `distribute` got merged](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/merge-faq.html) about a year ago - this was very important step simplifying the mess. So best place to start is probably [`setuptools` doc](http://pythonhosted.org//setuptools/). I shall reread it too, this time completely.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do that! :)